# Pending Intent Extras are not set for Launcher Application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-pendingintent, android-launcher

I have created a Launcher application named `HomeActivity` which has a `LaunchMode = SingleTask` and `CATEGORY_HOME` and `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`. This activity in turn starts new activities and some other applications as well.

The activity is connected with a Firebase Messaging service to get Push notifications. The Firebase service adds some extras (gathered from the push notification and sends them in Extras in `HomeActivity`

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
{
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(HomeActivity));
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);    
    intent.PutExtra(General.UPDATE_NOTIFIED, true);
    if(message.Data != null)
    {
        if (message.Data.Any())
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> kv in message.Data)
            {
                intent.PutExtra(kv.Key, kv.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
    builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.app_logo));
    builder.SetContentTitle(message.GetNotification().Title);
    builder.SetContentText(message.GetNotification().Body);
    builder.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound);
    builder.SetAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
    notificationManager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
}
```

Whenever the `HomeActivity` is on top and a push notification is received and clicked, I can access the Extras in `HomeActivity`'s `OnResume` function (I have overriden `OnNewIntent(Intent intent)`).

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    bool updateNotification = intent.GetBooleanExtra(General.UPDATE_NOTIFIED, false); //Check if Extra is set
    this.Intent = intent;
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);    
}
```

But when I am in another activity which is launched by the `HomeActivity` and a Push notification is clicked; the app does return to the `HomeActivity` but there are no Extras in the `Intent`.

I have tried all sorts of Flags, including but not limited to `NewTask`, `ClearTask` as well.

I am still unable to get why the Extras aren't being set when the notification is clicked at the time another activity is in place. What am I missing here.

Comment: I changed `GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);` to `GetActivity(this, DateTime.Now.Second, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);`, Still the same the extras are not coming

Comment: Changed the `GetActivity` to `GetActivity(this, DateTime.Now.Millisecond, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);` and removed the `intent.AddFlags` line but it's still the same result No extras

Comment: `GetActivity(this, DateTime.Now.Millisecond, intent, 0);` has the same outcome.

Comment: There should be no reason to use `singleTask` launch mode. Please explain why you think you need that. The special launch modes `singleTask` and `singleInstance` tend to create more problems than they solve. In general these are only needed if you are building a HOME-screen replacement.

Comment: The reason I am using Single Task is because my application is going to act as a launcher for my company's tablet system.

Comment: Can you receive `Extra` in your  `OnNewIntent` method ?

Comment: No the Extras are not coming in NewIntent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out what the issue is.

The Firebase system **WILL NOT** fire the `OnMessageReceived` method if you post a Notification with data (That is a display message).

What is needed to be done is that only `data` payload in the push notification will fire the `OnMessageRecieved` function which is responsible for setting the data.

So the notification should be like

```
{
    to: "topic | Registered device",
    data:{
          data1: "data_value1",
          data2: "data_value2",
          data3: "data_value3",
    }
}
```